# Using JQUERY, when do click in a checkbox, select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Look the following image. In it, I've got several tables, in each table has a checkBox which works as SelectAll (it's not implemented yet and must select the rest of the checkboxes.

[image]

This is the code which contains my razor view.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Classes.Count; i++) {
<span>@Model.Classes[i].Name</span>
<table class="monitor-class-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.CheckBox("selectAll-" + Model.Classes[0].ClassId)
        </th>
        <th>
            Online
        </th>
    </tr>

@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Classes[i].Students.Count; j++) {
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => ...)
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Classes[i].Students[j].Share)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => ...)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I don't know very well how to start using JQUERY (I guess is the best option). Select and unselect the checkboxes.

Comment: You need to do some research on javascript/jQUery and try to figure out how to do this on your own first.  Please come back with any questions you have when you run into implementation problems.

Comment: Why don't you show us the actual HTML that is outputted, and not the serverside code ?

Comment: I'd echo Mike's comment to a degree.  This is the sort of thing you can figure out by messing around with jQuery for a while, and reading the jQuery online docs.  It takes a bit more time, energy, and thought than asking strangers for help on the internet, but in the end you'll understand the material a lot better.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+select+all+checkboxes gives me a page full of lovely results

Comment: thank you, and sorry for the incovenience, I'm gonna check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can do it like this:

```
$('.select-all').change(function() {
    $('.check').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Here is basic demo implementation http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/YtMuh/

You can also make that `.select-all` checkbox automatically gets checked if you manually check all the rows (or gets unchecked if at least one row is not selected): http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/YtMuh/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how Razor renders things, so this might not be copy and paste, but this should get you started:

```
$('.selectAllCheckbox').on('change', function(ev) { 
    //assumes all of your "line item" checkboxes share a common class
    //this could easily be replaced with another selector "#mytable [type=checkbox]", etc
    $('.myLineItemCheckboxes').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

All that said, read the comments on your question.... there's some good advice there

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in 2 ways. First you can look at this persons solution here: http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript

The other way would be to set the same class to each checkbox and use jquery to set the checked attribute to true if the "all" box is checked.

```
$('.allchecked').attr('checked', true);
```